# Internationalization in Android

Tags: android, internationalization

hi guys can anyone guide me on implementation of Internationalization on Android platform. I am implementing my application in german language where i have too accept the inputs from user. The inputs are also having number, as germans use ',' character instead of '.' dot character and also date formats are different. So has anyone worked on such stuff. Please share your knowledge in this post wrt internationalization on android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you've read the [localization-guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html). That should help you translate your strings.

You'll also be interested in the [Format](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Format.html) classes, particularly [NumberFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) (for numbers, percentages, currency...) and [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html).

Comment: Thanks for the information but what i am really looking for is a general way to handle the number's. If i happen to add Japanese or chinese version or even make it too 10-12 languages,then accordingly i have to change the code for every number input in order to adjust to that locale. hope ur getting my point the more number of languages the more complex the code gets.

Comment: According to the docs, the NumberFormat.getInstance().format() is general. It formats the numbers according to the phones current locale, meaning that a user with a phone set to chinese should get the chinese formatting while a user with his phone set to japanese or swedish should get the japanese or swedish formatted version.